# What does "evte" mean in the openbox menu?

Tags: terminal, openbox

> Failed to execute child process "evte" (no such file or directory)

I often see this error  when I use Debian + Openbox.

It always happens when I click a program without GUI from the openbox menu, such as VIM or Emacs (terminal).

I export the menu.xml file by command "obamenu > menu.xml", then check it, I found that the command is "evte -e /usr/bin/emacs - NW"

What does "evte" mean ？ A terminal I need install? What is its full name？

The operations I have done before this error are listed below：

1. Configure my openbox like rc.xml or bind some hotkey.
2. Install some new terminal ,then switch the default terminal by "sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator "
3. **Maybe**, generate a new menu by command "obamenu"， I am not sure.

Here are some tips I found on obamenu's GitHub website.
https://github.com/xaosfiftytwo/obamenu/blob/master/obamenu

> #terminal_string = "evte -e"         # your favourites terminal exec string
> terminal_string = "terminator -e"         # your favourites terminal exec string

Replacing “evte” with “urxvt” or “uxterm” to execute command like "urxvt -e /usr/bin/emacs - NW" works normally.

Answer (score 0):

The [obamenu](https://github.com/xaosfiftytwo/obamenu/blob/master/obamenu)
text seems to imply that `terminator` and `evte` do similar things.

[terminator](https://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator) is defined as:

> Terminator is a program that allows users to set up flexible arrangements of GNOME terminals. It is aimed at those who normally arrange lots of terminals near each other, but don't want to use a frame based window manager.

The parameter `-e` is defined as:

```
-e, --command=COMMAND
    Runs the specified command instead of your default shell or profile specified command
```

So both seems to do the running of a terminal-command without a shell,
directly.